# Admob: One baner per activity or one baner for all?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, ads, banner

I'm making an app that will have multiple activities and my question is: Should I put only one banner for the whole app or a different banner per activity?

Now I'm doing the app and I've put only a banner for the whole app. I'm not sure about the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is totally your choice there is no restriction on the number of ad units you can use in a single app. The major differences will be in the approach

**Single ad unit** will have easier management but all stats will be counted under same ad unit and you'll not be able to make out which activity generated more revenue.

**Multiple ad units** will require more management in terms of creation and implementation. But you will be able to get more insight per activity in your app.

The approach you choose, again, totally depends on how you want to get it done.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a banner in only one activity, it will not show up in any other screens in your app. It is up to you if you want to do this. From my experience, you will get less ad revenue in such a situation.

Alternatively, you can make a single activity which holds the ad banner and a place holder for a fragment. Then instead of creating multiple activities, you can have multiple fragments. If you are unfamiliar with fragments, you should do some research. There are a lot of online tutorials to help you get started with them.

Comment: What if i created 5 banner ad units, and using them for 5 activities ? Now i'm in a situation like this.

Comment: @blackkara Yes, loading an ad banner in multiple activities should help increase your ad revenue. Alternatively, you could have a single activity with one ad banner and use fragments to implement multiple screens inside that activity instead of multiple activities.